# ActionCable websocket connection closed after 3 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, puma, actioncable

In both development and production environment, I notice that the websocket connection was getting closed every 3 minutes (exactly between 2.95 and 2.98 minutes each time, it seems).

The channel:

```
class SubscriptionIntentionsSelectionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    Rails.logger.info("subscribed")
    stream_for Project.find(6)
  end

  def receive(_data)
    self.class.broadcast_to(Project.find(6), status: :success, message: "pong")
  end
end
```

The client:

```
$('document').ready(() => {
  channel = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
    { channel: 'SubscriptionIntentionsSelectionChannel' }, {
    received(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    rejected() {
    },
    disconnected() {
    }
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    channel.send({ data: 'ping' });
  }, 10000);
});
```

I tried implementing a `setInterval` client-side to send messages to the channel to prevent any inactivity, but it doesn't help. No matter of the activity and the number of messages sent back and forth, the connection is always terminated after 3 minutes.

The connection is getting terminated normally. This is the logs from the server :

```
SubscriptionIntentionsSelectionChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
SubscriptionIntentionsSelectionChannel is streaming from subscription_intentions_selection:Z2lkOi8vYmxhc3QvUHJvamVjdC82
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-05-04 11:22:12 +0200
SubscriptionIntentionsSelectionChannel stopped streaming from subscription_intentions_selection:Z2lkOi8vYmxhc3QvUHJvamVjdC82
```

This is the logs from the developer's console in the browser :

[image]

I would suspect Redis or Puma to be closing the connection. Switching the cable.yml adapter from `redis` to `async` did not solve the issue. As of puma, the `worker_timeout` parameter in config/puma.rb did not help either... Maybe there is a way to get more information on how/why the connection is getting closed?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Puma issue? Does it persist if you use a different server (i.e. iodine)? AFAIK, the WebSocket networking code is handled by Rails, not by Puma. This is, in part, [why I wrote iodine](https://bowild.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/the-dark-side-of-the-rack/).